# NDSolve error 2nd order ode

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

```
m=2
w=2*Pi*0.9
wo=2*Pi
r=2*Pi*0.05
b=r*m
k=(wo^2)m
f[t]=10Cos[w*t]
ODEsx={m*x''[t]==(f[t]-b*x'[t]-k*x[t])}
sol=NDSolve[{ODEsx,x[0]==2,x'[0]==-2},x, {t,0, 40}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t]/.sol], {t, 0, 40}]
```

can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I keep getting NDSolve equation or list of equations expected instead of true in the first argument{2x''[t] 10Cos[5.65487t]-82πx[t]-0.628319′x[t]},x[0] 2,True .
(`NDSolve::deqn`)

Comment: It works for me as is but better to change `f[t] =10Cos[w*t]` to `f[t_]:=10Cos[w*t]`  V 13. Try again from clean kernel. You seem to have something else defined from before.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact values for known parameters.

```
m = 2;
w = 2*Pi*9/10;
wo = 2*Pi;
r = 2*Pi*1/20;
b = r*m;
k = (wo^2) m;
```

The definition of `f[t]` should include a pattern object:

```
f[t_] = 10 Cos[w*t];

ODEsx = m*x''[t] == (f[t] - b*x'[t] - k*x[t]);
```

The differential equation can be solved exactly with [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol = DSolve[{ODEsx, x[0] == 2, x'[0] == -2}, x[t], t][[1]] // 
  FullSimplify

(* {x[t] -> (1/(97539 π^2))
  E^(-((π t)/
    20)) (3198 (-190 + 61 π^2) Cos[1/20 Sqrt[1599] π t] + 
     15990 E^((π t)/20) (38 Cos[(9 π t)/5] + 9 Sin[(9 π t)/5]) + 
     2 Sqrt[
      1599] (-1810 + 61 (-20 + π) π) Sin[1/20 Sqrt[1599] π t])}*)

Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I am still getting the same error. do you know what else it could be?

Comment: Did you do as Nasser recommended and start with a fresh kernel? If so, what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I used Clear["Global`*"] and I'm using the wolframcloud notebook online.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code. Try copying and pasting my code.

Comment: yeah I tried that. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: nevermined i got it by using Remove[x]. thank you!